# How to make pytest exceptions cause breakpoint PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

PyCharm has this handy feature that, if enabled, you can get a breakpoint where the exception happens and debug it. However, when running pytests through PyCharm, when there is an exception it only shows the error in the console and does not cause exception breakpoints. I know pytest handles the exception by itself, but is there an option to make the pytest behave like running a regular python scripts and run the test sequentially and cause exception breakpoint when one test fails?